First pipeline does not trigger the second one
I created simple pipeline called mytrigger.yaml with the name of mytrigger in Azure DevOps.
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - test/pipeline

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'

- script: |
    echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.
    echo See https://aka.ms/yaml
  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'

And the second one called bytrigger.yaml with the name of bytrigger in Azure DevOps.
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: mySourcePipeline
    source: 'mytrigger'
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
          - test/pipeline

steps:
- script: |
    echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.
    echo See https://aka.ms/yaml
  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'

I tried both the yaml and classic mode method to finalize that task, however in both cases when I run mytrigger pipeline and go back to the Pipelines section on Azure DevOps I do not see that by trigger pipeline starts working after mytrigger succesfully was finished.
As you can see both are in the test/pipeline branch.
Independently both pipelines work, so my expectation is to trigger the bytrigger pipeline by mytrigger pipeline. How to fix it?
Besides of that, I am wondering how it will be shown on Azure DevOps. I mean when I click on the mytrigger pipelines there won't be mentioned about the second pipelines, will be? And If I would like to see the full workflow it might be configure also?

I can reproduce the same with your yaml.
This is because the Default branch for manual and scheduled builds setting is not test/pipeline branch on bytrigger pipeline.
To resolve, please edit the bytrigger pipeline -> Click vertical 3 dots -> Triggers -> YAML tab -> Get Sources -> Fix the Default branch for manual and scheduled builds setting as test/pipeline branch.

In addition, on bytrigger pipeline, it's recommended to add trigger: none at the top to exclude CI trigger.
#bytrigger.yml
trigger: none
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: mySourcePipeline
    source: mytrigger
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
          - test/pipeline

steps:
- script: |
    echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.
    echo See https://aka.ms/yaml
  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'

The pipeline resource trigger works:

You can find more details on doc Branch considerations:


Besides of that, I am wondering how it will be shown on Azure DevOps. I mean when I click on the mytrigger pipelines there won't be mentioned about the second pipelines, will be? And If I would like to see the full workflow it might be configure also?

Yes, if you click the mytrigger pipeline, there won't be mentioned about the bytrigger pipeline. If the trigger is setting correctly, after the 1st pipeline complete, the 2nd pipeline will start to run. And you can find the trigger info: Automatically triggered by <sourcepipeline> in the result page:


It works, thank you very much! I accept that question, however there was a second part of that main question.
Is there any way to see under the mytrigger pipeline the full flow like mytrigger job or stage -> bytrigger job or stage? It would much easier to read, manage, debug etc.
Typically when I run one standalone pipeline I see stages/jobs etc one by one, this is what I am looking for in that case.

Thanks @Kreg, glad to help! Since they are different pipelines, we cannot see the full workflow with both pipelines, but only current pipeline.

Ok, I see, thanks again for your support.
